# Database Object invalid or not set

Tags: ms-access

I have a report which contains 6 more reports, When I execute it, last 3 reports are left empty or sometime it says **Database object invalid** or **cannot open any more database**.
I have made one query which leads to 3 crosstab query which all are again used in a single query

> When I link all the tables of front end to back end reports give this
>   error but when I just Import the tables from backend and do not link
>   them, report executes fine

Comment: It may be because Access, much like Excel, cannot open the same object with the same name at the same time.  Even if they are in different locations.  It sounds like one or more of your tables is locked completely because it's already open by another process.

Comment: I am using only 4 tables and using them again and again in these reports via querry
All 7 reports use those tables and perform some mathematical task on the records, Actually there more are more than 1024 character in the query that is calculating and printing the report

Comment: Today, when I tried to open all the 6 subreports and 1 reports seperately 5 reports opened succesfuly but the 6th subreports produced an error " Invalid Object or Object not set" and all the macros, queries, and tables disapeared from the front end